# Order data by latest uploaded or created in django FBV

Tags: python, django, function, django-models, django-views

I have a list view where i display the uploaded records right now they are sorted by name i need to change them to sort them by created date(which is in model).

```
@login_required
def records(request, 
    template='records.html'):
    FBVPermission(IsUser).check(request)
    user = request.user.person.is_user

    data = {'user':user, 'records': user.records.all()}
    return render(request, template, data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
user.records.all().order_by("-date")
```

Assuming you have a field date, otherwise change it by whatever is relevant to your field.

The "-" means descending order, remove it for the opposite

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by